# Optional chaining for constructor calls?

Tags: swift, option-type, optional-chaining

I want to optionally cast an `NSNumber?` to an `Int?`, but the initialiser method for `Int` only takes `init(NSNumber)`, so I can't pass an `NSNumber?`.

Is there a way for me to compact this code so that it uses something like optional chaining?

```
// number: NSNumber?
let integer = number == nil ? nil : Int(number!)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Int` constructors don't take optional arguments.
You could "wrap" the construction into `map()`:

```
let number : NSNumber? = ...
let n = number.map { Int($0) } // `n` is an `Int?`
```

But here it is easier to use the `integerValue` property of `NSNumber` with optional chaining:

```
let n = number?.integerValue // `n` is an `Int?`
```

or just

```
let n = number as? Int // `n` is an `Int?`
```

since Swift "bridges" between `NSNumber` and `Int` automatically.